# snap refresh fails with 'broken assertion storage' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap

I run Ubuntu 20.04 with the regolith desktop environment. I got the notification to update the OS and tried to run the update with "Snap Store" but receive "Unable to update package-name".

Running "snap refresh" manually results in the following error message:

```
error: cannot refresh: cannot accept some assertions:

       - broken assertion storage, looking for snap-declaration: broken assertion storage, cannot decode assertion: assertion content/signature separator not found
```

Also "snap list" fails with:

```
error: cannot list local snaps! cannot find publisher details: broken assertion storage, looking
       for snap-declaration: broken assertion storage, cannot decode assertion: assertion
       content/signature separator not found
```

"systemctl status snapd.service" seems to be alright:

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-06-24 10:11:07 CEST; 54s ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 4471 (snapd)
      Tasks: 21 (limit: 16551)
     Memory: 20.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─4471 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad snapd[4471]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad snapd[4471]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad snapd[4471]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/20.04 (amd64) linux/5.4.0-37-generic.
Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad snapd[4471]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 1m40s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Jun 24 10:11:07 stefan-thinkpad systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
```

Any ideas what causes this issue?

Comment: This is happening on the same machine where my dpkg files are seemingly randomly getting corrupted. I suspect this is file system corruption, probably on the hard drive level.